# Associate JSON array element with event handler

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Is there a way, as I iterate through a JSON file to associate certain array elements with click handlers for a list?

What I have is this:

```
$.ajax(
{

   url: 'json/data.json',
   dataType : 'json',
   type: 'get',
   cache: false,
   success: function(fullJSONData)
   {
      $(fullJSONData.events).each(function(index, oneJSONLine)
      {
        $('#eventList').append(newEvent(index, oneJSONLine))
        $("#eventItem" + index).on("click", showEvent (fullJSONData.events[index]) );
      });
  },
  error: function (e) 
  {
      console.log("error " + e.message);
  }

});
```

This is not working because all of the event handlers for showEvent() point to the last value that was in index.  Can I get around this somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking the function, not passing it as reference.

Try

```
$(fullJSONData.events).each(function(index, oneJSONLine) {
    $('#eventList').append(newEvent(index, oneJSONLine))
    $("#eventItem" + index).on("click", function() {
        showEvent(fullJSONData.events[index]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of $(this) will solve your problems here. Not to confuse, but I would also use [$.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and [event delegates](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Also note that I'm selecting the '#eventList' item a single time to avoid re-selecting it for every iteration.

```
var eventList = $('#eventList');

$(fullJSONData.events).each(function(index, jsonLine)
{
   $(this).data("jsonData", jsonLine);
   eventList.append("<li>" + jsonLine.[some property for text] + "</li>");
}

eventList.on("click", "li", function()
{
   showEvent($(this).data("jsonData"));
});
```